# code highiglight not working comment

Tags: comments, syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin installed on my blog.
Code highlight working on post,but no comments..

I am showing the comment form with the different codes :

```
    <form  method="post" name="commentform" onsubmit="return false" id="commentform">
    <textarea name="comment" id="commentr" cols="50" rows="10" tabindex="4">  </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="send" id="send" value="1" />
    <span class="t"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="sendmain" name="sendmain"  onclick="_sendmain('<?php echo $post->ID; ?>');" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

What do you think the problem?
My English is bad, I'm sorry.
Thanks..

Comment: The plugin wasn't intended to work on comments, it's for post content

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But,it working another blogs on comments ..

Comment: Such as? Examples or it didn't happen

Comment: im solved problem.i added the to synatc highlighter class page :add_filter( 'get_comment_text',                       array( &$this, 'parse_shortcodes_comment' ),                      7 ); // Comments

Comment: Could you post that as an answer and mark it as accepted?